# get echo from php file from web to use in android app

Tags: php, android

I am trying to learn android by creating a simple app that has song lyrics stored in a database. Using HttpRequest and a Json Parser the app collects the songs' info and updates the UI.
it all works when it is stored locally.

I uploaded the php files to a domain and the database to db4free (a free testing server).

PHP file:

```
{
"message":"DB_CONNECT_OK",
"songsGroups":[
    {"groupName":"Christmas","language":"arabic"},
    {"groupName":"Christmas","language":"english"},
    {"groupName":"Easter","language":"arabic"},
    {"groupName":"Mary","language":"arabic"}],
"success":1
}
```

Json parser code:

```
try {
    if(method == "GET"){
        Log.i(TAG,"inGet");
        // request method is GET
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        Request httpGet = new Request.Builder().url(newUrl.toString()).build();

        Response httpResponse = httpClient.newCall(httpGet).execute();
        String httpEntity = httpResponse.body().string();
        //Log.d(TAG,"httpEntity " +  httpEntity);

        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(httpEntity.getBytes());
        Log.d(TAG, is.toString());
    }
}
```

I started debugging locally and globally, and realized that globally instead of getting the php echo, I am getting:

```
httpEntity = `
<html>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
    <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("6340d3d5958d62708984fc0193ccdb68");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; document.cookie="referrer="+escape(document.referrer); location.href="http://sitapp.byethost15.com/get_all_taratil_groups.php?ckattempt=1";</script>
    <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
    </body>
</html>`
```

The page source is: `

```
 {
    "message":"DB_CONNECT_OK",
    "songsGroups":   
        [{"groupName":"Christmas","language":"arabic"}
        ,{"groupName":"Christmas","language":"english"}
        ,{"groupName":"Easter","language":"arabic"}
        ,{"groupName":"Mary","language":"arabic"}],
    "success":1

 }`
```

Where did that JS came from?

So instead of the echo I am getting this JS from this line `String httpEntity = httpResponse.body().string();` while it was working fine while stored locally.

Comment: For future reference, please paste and format all applicable code rather than linking off site. That way if someone has your question later on and finds your question, they won't find a broken link.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my code and it worked after you set the responseStr

```
try (
    Response response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    setResponseStr(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

)
```

Comment: Can u explain please ?

Comment: @MarounSassine, I assumed you were calling the HttpRequest Method inside of a Async task.

Comment: Yes I did ! The thing that I'm getting Java Script instead of the Json response from the server. I found out that this might be due to cookies sent from the hosting server to the client... so I'm going to try other hosts.